# Prime number list code not working. How to fix it?

Tags: python

I've written the following code in python in order to produce a list of prime numbers up to a certain number but although the program runs without errors, the list produced are the odd numbers including 1 and 2. What can i do to fix the problem?
My code:

```
limit = int(input("enter an upper bound: "))
allnums = list(range(1, limit + 1))
for i in allnums:
    if i >= 3:
        for x in range(2, i) :
            if i % x == 0:
                allnums.remove(i)
                break
print(allnums)
```

Comment: Rule #1: You should not remove from list while iterating over it.

Comment: Socratica do really excellent, user-friendly, newbie-friendly tutorials on YouTube. Check out this on on generating lists of primes in Python: https://youtu.be/2p3kwF04xcA

Answer (score 0):

As per a comment says, removing elements from a list while iterating is not safe. See below code,

```
limit = int(input("enter an upper bound: "))
allnums = list(range(1, limit + 1))
seen_nums = []
for i in allnums:
    if i >= 3:
        seen_nums.append(i)
        for x in range(2, i) :
            if i % x == 0:
                allnums.remove(i)
                break
print(allnums)
```

If you view seen_nums you'll see that it only sees the even numbers. While iterating, you'll skip over the next element because that element gets moved 'up'. There are a number of ways to fix this. Sticking with your code structure, one way might be.

```
limit = int(input("enter an upper bound: "))
allnums = list(range(2, limit + 1))
primes = []
for i in allnums:
    is_prime = True
    if i >= 3:
        for x in range(2, i) :
            if i % x == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break
    if is_prime:
        primes.append(i)
print(primes)
```

P.S. Also, just to note, 1 is not a prime so I increased the range bottom limit from 1 to 2.

P.S.S. I also condensed your code a bit into one line if you'd like.

```
primes = [i for i in range(2,limit+1) if not any([i%x == 0 for x in range(2,i)])]
```